# How to disable admob lib on paid version

Tags: ios, admob, identifier

I have an app with two versions, one free and one paid. I use the same code with two different targets and I have preprocessor macro which defines a variable, so that way I can know when to load or not the ads.

This has been working fine so far, until today that Apple rejected my paid version because it has the advertising Identifier used by libGoogleAdMobAds.a

I include the lib, but never use it on the paid version, because no ads is shown, but if I don't show ads, they rejects the app because of this.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to compile my paid version without the admob lib when I'm including this lib in several files for my free app.

So, how can I organize my files to include admob files and include them on the free version but when compiling paid version leave them out of the binary and be able to compile my app?

Thanks

**Quick Update:**
This is an example of how I got my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"

<other imports here>

@interface testController : UITableViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate>{
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
}
```

I tried the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#ifdef FREE_VERSION
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADBannerViewDelegate.h"
#endif

<other imports here>

@interface testController : UITableViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate>{
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
}
```

So, I can't use the ifdef there, because if I use it on the imports, on the "interface" line, I get a not defined "GADBannerViewDelegate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 versions, so I guess you should have 2 different targets, 1 for free app and another for paid version, so firstly you should only add admob lib to target of free app. Then secondly is use below code to show admob for free version only

```
#ifdef FREE_VERSION
    // #import admob and show ad
#endif
```

Code in this ifdef condition will not be complied for paid version

[Update]
You can use below code for delegate

```
#ifdef FREE_VERSION
    #import abmob
    #define ARGS admobDelegate
#endif

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<ARGS>
```

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer, you just confirmed me what I thought, that I will have to do the ifdef of the lib on every file I import the lib and then same ifdef when I use the lib. is that what you tried to say?

Comment: Hi, yes, that is what you should do. But you can do this easier by creating a class to wrap admob (import and use), so you will only have to do ifdef in that class.

Comment: I understand, I'll try the ifdef on the different files and I'll see if that solves the problem. In the meantime, if you can provide me an example of how to wrap admob, it would be great. :)

Comment: Son, I edited my post to include some code. Can you see the problem that I'm having?

Comment: You should do some research before asking for help, there are a lot of example about ifdef condition on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 different targets, one for **free**, one for **pay**, simply remove `libGoogleAdMobAds.a` from the "Link Binary With Libraries" in the "Build Phases" section of the **pay** target.

If you are using CocoaPods, you can specify dependency per target, and only include a library in the **free** target like so:

```
target :free do
  pod 'Google-AdMob-Ads-SDK'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, but it won't compile because there are a lot of files that are importing the admob files for the free version (currently, I always import admob no matter the app version)

Comment: You *also* need to follow @SonNguyen advice, and have conditional assembly for only importing in **free** version